# Automated Removal of Visually Blank Images from Datasets

Tags: python, image-processing, signal-processing

I'm trying to filter out images that do not contain any or much visible structure from those that have a visible object in them so I can feed them into an self-supervised neural network.

I want to **keep** images like this, and I want to **remove** images like this:

[image: I want to keep images like this] [image: and I want to remove images like this]

I'm converting chemical imaging data to numpy arrays containing the signal intensity as float data, then use matplotlib to generate these images. To try to filter out the blank images, I first smoothed the images by setting each pixel value to the mean of its surrounding pixel to minimize noise. Then I found the standard deviation (σ) and mean (μ) and tried to filter out the bad images based on a σ, σ/μ, or σ^2/μ threshold, the latter of which somewhat worked. But if I set a threshold each image must exceed, such as σ^2/μ = 500, to apply to all datasets, it would remove far too many images from some or remove few to none from others.

Here's an example of me smoothing out the image and comparing σ^2/μ.

```
np.load(example.npy)
smoothed_image = np.empty(imgs.shape[1:])
for i, image in enumerate(imgs):
    for x in range(imgs.shape[1]):
        for y in range(imgs.shape[2]):
            # Select pixels to average
            subset = image[np.clip(x-3, 0, None):np.clip(x+4, None, image.shape[0]-1),
                           np.clip(y-3, 0, None):np.clip(y+4, None, image.shape[1]-1)]
            subset_ave = np.mean(subset)
            smoothed_image[x,y] = subset_ave
            smoothed_image[x,y]
    # Show stddev^2/mean and related image
    print(f'stddev^2/mean = {smoothed_image.std()**2/smoothed_image.mean()})
    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

I need to filter this data in an unsupervised fashion, so checking and changing the threshold for each dataset isn't an option. In addition, this process adds a significant amount of time to my data processing due to the ordering of my workflow. I tried to find other options online, but I don't think I know what to search to find information about this specific issue.

Here is some [example data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tEHNgZYNqxQQh11saZPi54hWKExqWctA/view?usp=sharing). Selecting any index on axis 0 (ex. images[8]) will give you a single image array.

Any suggestions on what methods I could use to filter images like this, preferably without very time consuming computation?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: since those are just plots of the actual data, you should work with the actual data. don't even think about processing any plot pictures. there's likely a proper way to do the same operations on the actual data instead. -- looks like various "moments" could quantify the "spread" of these heatmaps -- please provide a [mre], or at least the source data, for people to experiment with, if they are so inclined.

Comment: I have been working on the data itself, I just thought it would be much easier for people to visualize the problem. I updated the post with an example dataset that I will be working with.

Comment: @EmersonH Analyze the distribution of pixels in the histogram of each image and decide based on that

Comment: ah, so it _is_ image data! I thought that were some type of heatmap/scatter plot. my bad. -- I concur, standard deviation, or some statistics on a histogram, should be able to capture the essence-- by the way... each slice's intensities seem to be scaled differently... and debris/noise may affect what is the max() and what _should_ be considered the maximum. perhaps apply a median blur/filter before considering any maxima

Comment: Thanks for the responses! Using a histogram to analyze images after median blur worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is to use an aggressive threshold to suppress nearly all the noise, then simply take the sum of the image and set a threshold that way, kind of like:

```
image_thresh = image - 100 # where image is a numpy array and 100 would surely suppress noise, but not features
image_thresh[image_thresh<0] = 0
image_sum = np.sum( image_thresh )
```

Another way is to use OpenCV and look for ellipses above a certain size. You could reference such a page as [this one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-circles-and-ellipses-in-an-image-using-opencv-python/) to get started on that.

Comment: that is equivalent to `image[image >= 100].sum()`. subtracting 100 from the entire image, only to compare against 0, and then mutating once more (setting to 0), is needlessly complicated. perhaps "lurk more". -- this question is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) and it's our job to smell that and _not_ just do what OP thinks they want, but to figure out what they need

Comment: Agreed, my thresholding solution is needlessly complicated. On the other note, I thought it was pretty obvious that what the OP asked for was what they needed. They don't want to spend days labelling images for their neural network by hand, so they want an unsupervised way to do it. This is a common task that sometimes requires uncommon approaches, hence their question. I would have loved to put my "answer" in a comment, but my rep is too low.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned this as well. The noise is often higher intensity than some well defined images, ie if I do a simple threshold or subtract before summing, many if not most well defined images would be lost before all of the bad images are removed.